# How to create a Notification or Toast from startup service?

Tags: java, android, service

I'm working on an basic reminder application which has a user interface capable to log user set dates to an sqlite database. To complete my application I'd like to have a service which starts and keep running in the background when the phone is restarted, so I can periodically check the database and display a notification message to the user if any of the dates are close.

I can start my service on startup (I can send LOG messages to Android Studio) but I can't display notifications. It seems the examples I have found always rely on an activity, but how would I have an activity without having the main app running? (and ofcourse thats the point of my background service, the user doesnt have to open the main app).

Q1: How can I display a Toast message from this service?

Q2: How can I display a notification from this service?

```
public class autostartservice extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                    Log.i("myDebug", "Just wait here couple second until the phone boots all the way");
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "Look at this Toast! Cool uh?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All these kind of things uses a Context to show a Toast or a Notification. A Service "acts as" a Context, so you can do quite the same things as you do in an Activity. You only have to pay attention that a normal Service runs in the same Thread of the UserInterface, so if the Service is blocking (waiting some event in a Blocking way) even the UserInterface is blocked and Notifications or Toasts cannot be displayed while blocked/frozen.

Comment: Ok, so what do I need to do differently to display a Toast / Notification?

Comment: Post a Runnable/Code by using "runOnUiThread()" method or by posting a Message on a MainThread Handler. I think you have to read some guide about them before the usage.